# executing a python script within another python script

Tags: python, scripting, operating-system, subprocess, dataset

I wanted to run this script that saves images generated by a TDW script but the TDW script is definitely not running.

```
import glob
import os
import cv2
import subprocess
i = 0
frameSize = (512, 512)
path = 'CRIPP/annotations/icqa_dataset/IID/json'
for i in range(0, 1):
    new_path = path + f'/example_{i}.json'
    cmd = "recreate.py -json={new_path}"
    os.system(cmd)
    #subprocess.call(['recreate.py', '-json='+new_path])
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to run script using python.
Change cmd line to `cmd = "python recreate.py -json={new_path}"`